# How can I merge code below in laravel route?

Tags: php, laravel

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

//part A
Route::group(['namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers'], function()
{        
  Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'permission']], function() {  
        Route::group(['prefix' => 'users'], function() {
            Route::get('/', 'UsersController@index')->name('users.index');
            Route::get('/create', 'UsersController@create')->name('users.create');
            Route::post('/create', 'UsersController@store')->name('users.store');
            Route::get('/{user}/show', 'UsersController@show')->name('users.show');
            Route::get('/{user}/edit', 'UsersController@edit')->name('users.edit');
            Route::patch('/{user}/update', 'UsersController@update')->name('users.update');
            Route::delete('/{user}/delete', 'UsersController@destroy')->name('users.destroy');
        });

        Route::resource('roles', RolesController::class);
        Route::resource('permissions', PermissionsController::class);
        Route::group(['prefix' => 'hospitals'], function() {
            Route::get('/', 'HospitalsController@index')->name('hospital.index');
            Route::get('/create', 'HospitalsController@create')->name('hospital.create');
            Route::post('/create', 'HospitalsController@store')->name('hospital.store');
            Route::get('/{post}/show', 'HospitalsController@show')->name('hospital.show');
            Route::get('/{post}/edit', 'HospitalsController@edit')->name('hospital.edit');
            Route::patch('/{post}/update', 'HospitalsController@update')->name('hospital.update');
            Route::delete('/{post}/delete', 'HospitalsController@destroy')->name('hospital.destroy');
        });     
    });
});

//Part B
Auth::routes();

Route::get('/', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'root'])->name('root');
Route::post('/update-profile/{id}', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'updateProfile'])->name('updateProfile');
Route::post('/update-password/{id}', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'updatePassword'])->name('updatePassword');
Route::get('{any}', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('index');
//Language Translation
Route::get('index/{locale}', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'lang']);
```

I have the code above in web.php. I have to merge both part in the above file.
I have tried keeping auth commented out and merge the controller part in one group and place it inside the middleware section, but it's not working.

Comment: _What_ didn't work? Do you get any errors? What exactly do you need to merge?

Comment: please explain what you need to achieve maybe post the end result you want so others can understand and help

Comment: I want them under one auth .because Auth::routes(); is creating unnecessary problem.and some hidden routes are also associated with that

Answer (score 0):

The question  was hard to understand, so I hope I got your issue right.
Also please share the code that you made after merging part A and part B, and the error that your are getting (if you are getting any).
does this work?

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::group(['namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers'], function()
{        
  Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'permission']], function() {
        //the code from part B                          
        Route::get('/', 'HomeController@root`')->name('root');
        Route::get('/update-profile/{id}', 'HomeController@updateProfile`')->name('updateProfile');
        Route::get('/update-password/{id}', 'HomeController@updatePassword`')->name('updatePassword');
        Route::get('{any}', 'HomeController@index`')->name('index');
        Route::get('index/{locale}', 'HomeController@lang`');

        Route::group(['prefix' => 'users'], function() {
            Route::get('/', 'UsersController@index')->name('users.index');
            Route::get('/create', 'UsersController@create')->name('users.create');
            Route::post('/create', 'UsersController@store')->name('users.store');
            Route::get('/{user}/show', 'UsersController@show')->name('users.show');
            Route::get('/{user}/edit', 'UsersController@edit')->name('users.edit');
            Route::patch('/{user}/update', 'UsersController@update')->name('users.update');
            Route::delete('/{user}/delete', 'UsersController@destroy')->name('users.destroy');
        });

        Route::resource('roles', RolesController::class);
        Route::resource('permissions', PermissionsController::class);
        Route::group(['prefix' => 'hospitals'], function() {
            Route::get('/', 'HospitalsController@index')->name('hospital.index');
            Route::get('/create', 'HospitalsController@create')->name('hospital.create');
            Route::post('/create', 'HospitalsController@store')->name('hospital.store');
            Route::get('/{post}/show', 'HospitalsController@show')->name('hospital.show');
            Route::get('/{post}/edit', 'HospitalsController@edit')->name('hospital.edit');
            Route::patch('/{post}/update', 'HospitalsController@update')->name('hospital.update');
            Route::delete('/{post}/delete', 'HospitalsController@destroy')->name('hospital.destroy');
        });     
    });
});

Auth::routes();
```

Comment: I am trying it and it is giving error ```Symfony
 \ 
Component
 \ 
Routing
 \ 
Exception
 \ 
RouteNotFoundException
PHP 8.1.5
9.0.2
Route [logout] not defined.```  It is because there are some more routes associated with Auth ::Routes()..

Comment: please share the code that is throwing said error. Are you putting ```Auth::routes();``` inside part A perhaps? because it needs to stay outside...

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/storagelink', function () {
    Artisan::call('storage:link');
    return "Done Link Created";
});
Route::get('/permission', function () {
    Artisan::call('permission:create-permission-routes');
    return "Done Permission Created";
});
Route::get('/clear', function() {
    Artisan::call('cache:clear');
    Artisan::call('config:clear');
    Artisan::call('view:clear');
    Artisan::call('route:clear');
    return "Cleared!";
    });

Route::group(['namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers'], function () {
    Route::group(['middleware' => ['guest']], function () {
       
        Route::get('login', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
        Route::post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
        Route::post('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');
        // Route::stration Routes...
        Route::get('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm')->name('register');
        Route::post('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@register');
        // Route::word Reset Routes...s
        Route::get('password/reset', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm');
        Route::post('password/email', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail');
        Route::get('password/reset/{token}', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm');
        Route::post('password/reset', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset');
        
        //Language Translation
        Route::get('index/{locale}', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'lang']);
        
    });

    Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'permission']], function () {
        Route::get('{any}', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('index');
        Route::get('/', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'root'])->name('root');
        //Update User Details
        Route::post('/update-profile/{id}', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'updateProfile'])->name('updateProfile');
        Route::post('/update-password/{id}', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'updatePassword'])->name('updatePassword');

        // Route::get('/hospitals', [App\Http\Controllers\HospitalsController::class, 'index'])->name('hospitals');

        Route::group(['prefix' => 'users'], function () {
            Route::post('/register', 'Auth\RegisterController@register')->name('users.register');
            Route::get('/', 'UsersController@index')->name('users.index');
            Route::get('/create', 'UsersController@create')->name('users.create');
            Route::post('/create', 'UsersController@store')->name('users.store');
            Route::get('/{user}/show', 'UsersController@show')->name('users.show');
            Route::get('/{user}/edit', 'UsersController@edit')->name('users.edit');
            Route::patch('/{user}/update', 'UsersController@update')->name('users.update');
            Route::delete('/{user}/delete', 'UsersController@destroy')->name('users.destroy');
        });
        Route::get('districts', 'DistrictsController@index')->name('districts.index');
        // Route::resource('hospitals', HospitalsController::class);
        Route::resource('roles', RolesController::class);
        Route::resource('permissions', PermissionsController::class);
       
    });
});
```

I tried to unwrap auth::route and kept it under middleware ..